# Sending the path of clicked item in recyclerview to a dialog activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a RecyclerView, long click listener on any item will open delete dialog, the delete dialog contain two buttons, delete and cancel, when clicking on delete a document in Firestore should be deleted.
Now, how can I get the path of clicked item and send it to the delete dialog?
I can't use (intent) in dialog activity!
Note: I know there is other way to make a dialog but I faced the same problem..

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_std_in_this_class);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String MyG = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MYG);
   query = db.collection("aaa").document("bbb").collection("ddd")
   .document(UserId).collection(MyG).whereEqualTo("f",1);

   FirestoreRecyclerOptions <infoOfMyStd> options = new 
   FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<infoOfMyStd>()
                            .setQuery(query, infoOfMyStd.class)
                            .build();

            mystdsAdapter = new MyStdsAdapter(options);


    mystdsAdapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new MyStdsAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            infoOfMyStd infoofmystd = documentSnapshot.toObject(infoOfMyStd.class);
            String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyStdInThisClass.this, DeleteDialog.class);

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STD_PATH, path);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    });


    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_stds_recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);    //for performane reasons
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mystdsAdapter);
    mystdsAdapter.startListening();

    ////

}
```

And ViewHolder in the the adapter:

```
            cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                DeleteDialog dialog = new DeleteDialog(v.getContext());
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Also in the Adapter:

```
public interface OnItemLongClickListener {
    public boolean onItemLongClicked(int position, DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot);
}
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener Llistener){
    this.Llistener = Llistener;
}
```

Appreciate your help..

Comment: can you see any error log in logcat? could you please add this information to your question?

Comment: @JanHernandez No, I just want to send the path of clicked item to dialog so I can delete it in firestore, and I can't use getIntent() in dialog activity. what should I do?